# GLFW Can't create window no matter what

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, glew

I'm running glfw on Windows 7 64-bit but I'm running the 32-bit version of glfw and 32-bit version of mingw, and I have also tried 64-bit version in vs 2019. The thing is glfw successfully initialized but the create window function fails(i can guarantee) and searching on the internet, I can't find the right solution. Anyway here's my code:

```
#include "include/glfw3.h"

// Entry point
int main() {
    // Initialize glfw
    if (!glfwInit()) return -1;

    // Window hints
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);

    // Create widnow
    GLFWwindow* wind = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "All", NULL, NULL);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(wind);
    if (wind == NULL) return -2; 

    // Main loop
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose) {
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    // Terminate glfw
    glfwDestroyWindow(wind);
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

No compilation errors. Any help appreciated.

Comment: I'm having a bit trouble understanding the documentation, so do you declare the error_callback  because I'm getting an error saying it's not declared?

Comment: But what should it return?

Comment: Yes, but I might need a refresher.

Comment: [Slap a capture-less lambda in there](https://github.com/genpfault/glfw-mcve-base/blob/master/src/main.cpp#L58) and call it a day :)  `glfwSetErrorCallback( []( int, const char* desc ) { std::cerr << desc << "\n"; std::exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); } );`

Answer (score 1):

`glfwWindowShouldClose` is a function to check if the window should close, not a global bool. So the loop condition `!glfwWindowShouldClose` actually judges if this thing: "`glfwWindowShouldClose`" (by which you actually mean a function pointer), is `nullptr`. As `glfwWindowShouldClose` is a concrete function, the answer is no in our case, the loop will be skipped and no error will occur.

To fix it, turn this:

```cpp
    // Main loop
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose) {
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
```

into this:

```cpp
    // Main loop
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(wind)) {
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out but this doesn't seem to be the case because the window fails to create in the first place(I tested my program on another computer and it worked) and I think the problem is the current laptop I'm using doesn't support openGL at all! I'm gonna return home in a few days so ill be at full control. Thanks for the help.